# Jsoup Respond: Every second sign is garbage (encoding issue?)

Tags: java, character-encoding, jsoup

As part of an Android app I use a little Java/Jsoup based HTML-Crawler. This worked actually fine until some weeks ago but now I receive very strange results when I Parse the results.
This is the page I am crawling (all the errors occur before I'm logged in): https://www.stine.uni-hamburg.de

And this is how I get the Jsoup Respond object:

```
Connection connection = Jsoup
                .connect("https://stine.uni-hamburg.de/")
                .header("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8")
                .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0")
                .referrer("https://www.stine.uni-hamburg.de/scripts/mgrqispi.dll")
                .method(postData == null ? Connection.Method.GET : Connection.Method.POST)
                .timeout(10000)
                .cookies(m_cookies);
Connection.Response response = connection.execute();
```

I also tried already to remove all parts of the connection parameters which are not absolutely necessary and tried a simple

```
Jsoup.parse(new URL("https://www.stine.uni-hamburg.de), 10000);

System.out.println("resp: " + response);
System.out.println("status: " + response.statusCode());
System.out.println("content-type: " + response.contentType());
System.out.println("header: " + response.headers().toString());
System.out.println("content: " + response.parse().body().toString());
```

With any method the result looks like this:

```
resp: org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response@756535fa
status: 200
content-type: text/html
header: {ETag="09cd9ca88eccf1:0", Date=Fri, 28 Nov 2014 20:53:49 GMT, Vary=Accept-Encoding, Content-Length=1210, Last-Modified=Mon, 20 Oct 2014 17:10:48 GMT, Content-Encoding=gzip, Accept-Ranges=bytes, Content-Type=text/html, X-Powered-By=ASP.NET, Server=Microsoft-IIS/7.5}
content: ��<��!��D��O��C��T��Y��P��E�� ��H��T��M��L�� ��P��U��B��L��I��C�� ��"��-��/��/��W��3��C��/��/��D��T��D�� ��H��T��M��L�� ��4��.��0��1��/��/��E��N��"�� ��"��h��t��t��p��:��/��/��w��w��w��.��w��3��.��o��r��g��/��T��R��/��h��t��m��l��4��/��s��t��r��i��c��t��.��d��t��d��"��>��
��<��h��t��m��l��>��
��  ��<��h��e��a��d��>��
��  ��
��  ��<��!��-��-��
��  ����� ��D��A��T��E��N��L��O��T��S��E��N�� ��I��N��F��O��R��M��A��T��I��O��N��S��S��Y��S��T��E��M��E�� ��G��M��B��H��
��  ��e��-��m��a��i��l��:�� ��  ��  ��i��n��f��o��@��d��a��t��e��n��l��o��t��s��e��n��.��d��e��
��  ��w��e��b��:�� ��   ��  ��  ��h��t��t��p��:��/��/��w��w��w��.��d��a��t��e��n��l��o��t��s��e��n��.��d��e��
��  ��
��  ��c��u��s��t��o��m��e��r��:�� ��    ��  ��u��h��h��
��  ��v��e��r��s��i��o��n��:�� ��   ��  ��5��.��4��0��.��0��0��8��
��  ��f��i��l��e��n��a��m��e��:��   ��  ��i��n��d��e��x��.��h��t��m��
��/��/��-��-��>��
��
��  ��
��  ��  ��<��t��i��t��l��e��>��U��n��i��v��e��r��s��i��t�����t�� ��H��a��m��b��u��r��g��<��/��t��i��t��l��e��>��
��  ��  ��  ��
��  ��  ��<��m��e��t��a�� ��h��t��t��p��-��e��q��u��i��v��=��"��X��-��U��A��-��C��o��m��p��a��t��i��b��l��e��"�� ��c��o��n��t��e��n��t��=��"��I��E��=��E��m��u��l��a��t��e��I��E��9��"�� ��/��>�� ��<��!��-��-�� ��I��E��9�� ��d��o��c��u��m��e��n��t�� ��m��o��d��e�� ��o��n��l��y�� ��-��-��>��
��
��  ��  ��<��m��e��t��a�� ��h��t��t��p��-��e��q��u��i��v��=��"��c��a��c��h��e��-��c��o��n��t��r��o��l��"��  �� ��   ��c��o��n��t��e��n��t��=��"��n��o��-��c��a��c��h��e��"�� ��/��>��
��  ��  ��<��m��e��t��a�� ��h��t��t��p��-��e��q��u��i��v��=��"��e��x��p��i��r��e��s��"�� �� ��  ��  ��  ��c��o��n��t��e��n��t��=��"��-��1��"�� ��/��>��
��  ��  ��<��m��e��t��a�� ��h��t��t��p��-��e��q��u��i��v��=��"��p��r��a��g��m��a��"�� ��    ��  ��  ��  ��c��o��n��t��e��n��t��=��"��n��o��-��c��a��c��h��e��"�� ��/��>��
��  ��  ��<��m��e��t��a�� ��h��t��t��p��-��e��q��u��i��v��=��"��p��r��a��g��m��a��"�� ��    ��  ��  ��  ��c��o��n��t��e��n��t��=��"��n��o��-��c��a��c��h��e��"�� ��/��>��
��  ��  ��<��m��e��t��a�� ��h��t��t��p��-��e��q��u��i��v��=��"��p��r��a��g��m��a��"�� ��    ��  ��  ��  ��c��o��n��t��e��n��t��=��"��n��o��-��c��a��c��h��e��"�� ��/��>��
��
��  ��  ��<��m��e��t��a�� ��n��a��m��e��=��"��v��i��e��w��p��o��r��t��"�� ��c��o��n��t��e��n��t��=��"��w��i��d��t��h��=��d��e��v��i��c��e��-��w��i��d��t��h��,�� ��i��n��i��t��i��a��l��-��s��c��a��l��e��=��1��,��u��s��e��r��-��s��c��a��l��a��b��l��e��=��0��"�� ��/��>��
��  ��
��  ��  ��  ��  ��
��  ��  ��<��l��i��n��k�� ��r��e��l��=��"��a��p��p��l��e��-��t��o��u��c��h��-��i��c��o��n��"�� ��h��r��e��f��=��"��/��g��f��x��/��u��h��h��/��i��c��o��n��s��/��i��p��h��o��n��e��_��t��o��u��c��h��_��i��c��o��n��.��p��n��g��"�� ��t��y��p��e��=��"��i��m��a��g��e��/��g��i��f��"�� ��/��>��
��
��  ��  ��<��m��e��t��a�� ��h��t��t��p��-��e��q��u��i��v��=��"��r��e��f��r��e��s��h��"�� ��c��o��n��t��e��n��t��=��"��0��;�� ��U��R��L��=��/��s��c��r��i��p��t��s��/��m��g��r��q��i��s��p��i��.��d��l��l��?��A��P��P��N��A��M��E��=��C��a��m��p��u��s��N��e��t��&��P��R��G��N��A��M��E��=��S��T��A��R��T��P��A��G��E��_��D��I��S��P��A��T��C��H��&��A��R��G��U��M��E��N��T��S��=��-��N��0��0��0��0��0��0��0��0��0��0��0��0��0��0��1��"�� ��/��>��
��  ��  ��  ��  ��
��  ��  ��<��l��i��n��k�� �� �� ��h��r��e��f��=��"��/��c��s��s��/��_��d��e��f��a��u��l��t��/��d��l��.��s��t��a��r��t��p��a��g��e��.��c��s��s��"��   ��  ��  ��r��e��l��=��"��s��t��y��l��e��s��h��e��e��t��"�� �� ��t��y��p��e��=��"��t��e��x��t��/��c��s��s��"��   ��/��>��
��  ��  ��
��  ��  ��<��s��c��r��i��p��t�� ��t��y��p��e��=��"��t��e��x��t��/��j��a��v��a��s��c��r��i��p��t��"�� ��s��r��c��=��"��/��j��s��/��m��o��b��i��l��e��_��m��a��s��t��e��r��/��j��q��u��e��r��y��.��j��s��"��>��<��/��s��c��r��i��p��t��>��
��  ��  ��<��s��c��r��i��p��t�� ��t��y��p��e��=��"��t��e��x��t��/��j��a��v��a��s��c��r��i��p��t��"�� ��s��r��c��=��"��/��j��s��/��m��o��b��i��l��e��_��m��a��s��t��e��r��/��o��n��m��e��d��i��a��q��u��e��r��y��.��m��i��n��.��j��s��"��>��<��/��s��c��r��i��p��t��>��
��
��  ��<��/��h��e��a��d��>��
��  ��
��  ��<��b��o��d��y��>��    ��  ��
��  ��  ��<��d��i��v�� ��i��d��=��"��w��r��a��p��p��e��r��"��>��
��  ��  ��  ��<��a�� ��h��r��e��f��=��"��h��t��t��p��:��/��/��w��w��w��.��u��n��i��-��h��a��m��b��u��r��g��.��d��e��"�� ��t��i��t��l��e��=��"��e��x��t��e��r��n�� ��w��w��w��.��u��n��i��-��h��a��m��b��u��r��g��.��d��e��"��>��
��  ��  ��  ��  ��<��i��m��g�� ��b��o��r��d��e��r��=��"��0��"�� ��i��d��=��"��l��o��g��o��"�� ��s��r��c��=��"��/��g��f��x��/��u��h��h��/��l��o��g��o��.��p��n��g��"�� ��a��l��t��=��"��L��o��g��o�� ��U��n��i��v��e��r��s��i��t�����t�� ��H��a��m��b��u��r��g��"�� ��/��>��
��  ��  ��  ��<��/��a��>��
��  ��  ��  ��
��  ��  ��  ��<��u��l�� ��i��d��=��"��l��a��n��g��M��e��n��u��"��>��
��  ��  ��  ��  �� �� ��<��!��-��-�� ��/��/�� ��F��O��R��W��A��R��D��I��N��G�� ��0��0��1�� ��G��e��r��m��a��n�� ��/��/�� ��-��-��>��
��  ��  ��  ��  ��  ��<��l��i��>��<��a�� ��c��l��a��s��s��=��"��i��m��g�� ��i��m��g��_��L��a��n��g��G��e��r��m��a��n��"�� ��h��r��e��f��=��"��/��s��c��r��i��p��t��s��/��m��g��r��q��i��s��p��i��.��d��l��l��?��A��P��P��N��A��M��E��=��C��a��m��p��u��s��N��e��t��&��P��R��G��N��A��M��E��=��S��T��A��R��T��P��A��G��E��_��D��I��S��P��A��T��C��H��&��A��R��G��U��M��E��N��T��S��=��-��N��0��0��0��0��0��0��0��0��0��0��0��0��0��0��1��"��>��d��e��<��/��a��>��<��/��l��i��>��
��  ��  ��  ��  ��  ��  ��  ��  ��
��  ��  ��  ��  �� ��<��!��-��-�� ��/��/�� ��F��O��R��W��A��R��D��I��N��G�� ��0��0��2�� ��E��n��g��l��i��s��h�� ��/��/�� ��-��-��>��
��  ��  ��  ��  ��  ��<��l��i��>��<��a�� ��c��l��a��s��s��=��"��i��m��g�� ��i��m��g��_��L��a��n��g��E��n��g��l��i��s��h��"�� ��h��r��e��f��=��"��/��s��c��r��i��p��t��s��/��m��g��r��q��i��s��p��i��.��d��l��l��?��A��P��P��N��A��M��E��=��C��a��m��p��u��s��N��e��t��&��P��R��G��N��A��M��E��=��S��T��A��R��T��P��A��G��E��_��D��I��S��P��A��T��C��H��&��A��R��G��U��M��E��N��T��S��=��-��N��0��0��0��0��0��0��0��0��0��0��0��0��0��0��2��"��>��e��n��<��/��a��>��<��/��l��i��>��
��  ��  ��  ��  ��  ��  ��  ��  ��
��  ��  ��  ��  ��  ��  ��  ��  ��
��  ��  ��  ��  ��  ��  ��  ��<��/��u��l��>��
��  ��  ��  ��
��  ��  ��<��/��d��i��v��>��
��  ��<��/��b��o��d��y��>��
��<��/��h��t��m��l��>��
��
```

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:** I noticed something else: This error only occurs, if I retrieve the base url directly (i.e. "https://www.stine.uni-hamburg.de"). If I on the other hand call Jsoup on BASE_URL/scripts/mgrqispi.dll I recieve an valid result (using the same settings).
However I also need the base url to render correctly, since the page uses this forwarding annoyance for creating the session.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had something like this a while back, if I can find the code I'll post it on here.

But yes, it might be related to character encoding.  Take a look at maybe reading it as an input stream with the encoding set explicitly

```
//from docs - http://jsoup.org/apidocs/
parse(InputStream inputstream, String charsetName, String baseUri) 


//example
Jsoup.parse(in , "ISO-8859-2", url);
```

You'll want to try and read the Url as an inputstream.  Something maybe like this?

```
InputStream inputstream =new URL(url).openStream();
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried your suggestion and it didn't solve the problem. But I noticed something else and added the information to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was now able to workaround the problem by using the first URL to which the crawled page forwards to as entry point for the script. I still don't understand how this strange response has occurred though. If I was using a wrong character encoding I would have expected that some characters could not have been displayed but not something like this... However, since I got the program working now I consider this thread as closed. If you think you might know a solution, feel free to post it and I'll test it so that it can be helpful for future readers.